Stationary Check (ADF, KPSS and ACF PACF Plot) for SARIMAX model
I'm still confused about whether my data is stationary in terms of variance and mean or not, because based on the ADF test and KPSS test the data already shows stationary (because it rejects H0) but if you look at the data plot it seems like it's still not stationary.
I plan to conduct experiments using the SARIMAX model with Discount as an Exogenous variable. So, can anyone give me some input on this? Please help me as I am having great difficulty getting this done :(( It would be awesome if you guys could guide my way through this problem. Thank you.
